# Does SoftLayer support change virtual guest billing type(hourly<->monthly)

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I just change  and by SL API

```
Request URL:  PUT https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/{vm_id}.json
Parameters:  {"parameters":[{"dedicatedAccountHostOnlyFlag":false,"domain":"softlayer.com","hostname":"{vm-hostname}","hourlyBillingFlag":false}]}
Response: True
....
Request URL:  GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/vm_id.json?objectMask=mask%5Bid%2C+maxMemory%2C+startCpus%2C+dedicatedAccountHostOnlyFlag%2C+hourlyBillingFlag%2C+datacenter%5Bname%5D%2C+primaryBackendIpAddress%2C+fullyQualifiedDomainName%5D
Parameters:
Response:
```

{"dedicatedAccountHostOnlyFlag":false,"fullyQualifiedDomainName":"{vm-hostname}.softlayer.com","id":{vm_id},"maxMemory":1024,"startCpus":1,"datacenter":{"name":"lon02"},"hourlyBillingFlag":true,"primaryBackendIpAddress":"vm_ip"}

`hourlyBillingFlag` had not be change as I request.

Same situation as `dedicatedAccountHostOnlyFlag`.

So Does SL support these changes? If yes, which API should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Nope that is not supported even using the UI you cannot do that

Comment: Hi, I just tried to place an order to transfer public VM to dedicated host VM. And get error from API: `{"error":"Invalid price 1 GB (Dedicated Host) (200339) provided on the order container. Please select a dedicated instance RAM price to order a dedicated instance.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Order_Item_Invalid"}`. The message confused me because I raise CPU from 1 public to 2 dedicated. Is it invalid to chang VM's CPU like that?

Comment: you can do that, the issue is that you are using the wrong price try another one

Comment: Hi, I just clarify that I tried to use order to change RAM and dedicated host both but failed.

Comment: using the API you only can change the same items as in the portal, first try to do what you want using the portal.